# how to implement these Activity code on Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

confuse to implement these code to Fragment.java
could you please to implement these code from Activity to Fragment? I want to make auto update location and show the address by click the "Fetch" button.

I have these MainActivity.java code, I want to implement these to Fragment.java but i don't understand how to do it.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.parsaniahardik.addresscurrentlocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.karumi.dexter.Dexter;
import com.karumi.dexter.MultiplePermissionsReport;
import com.karumi.dexter.PermissionToken;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.DexterError;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequest;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.PermissionRequestErrorListener;
import com.karumi.dexter.listener.multi.MultiplePermissionsListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
  //  private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private Double latitude = 0.00;
    private Double longitude = 0.00;
    private TextView textView, tvCountry, tvCity, tvState, tvPincode, tvFeature;
    private Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        requestMultiplePermissions();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

      //  mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        checkLocation();

        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tvCountry = findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
        tvState = findViewById(R.id.tvState);
        tvCity = findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
        tvPincode = findViewById(R.id.tvPincode);
        tvFeature = findViewById(R.id.tvFeature);
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setAddress(latitude,longitude);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

            // mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if(!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private void  requestMultiplePermissions(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //startLocationUpdates();
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                            openSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
    }

    private void openSettingsDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Required Permissions");
        builder.setMessage("This app require permission to use awesome feature. Grant them in app settings.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Take Me To SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    private void setAddress(Double latitude, Double longitude){

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addresses.size() > 0) {
            Log.d("max", " " + addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex());

            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

            addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            textView.setText(address);
            tvFeature.setText(knownName);
            tvCountry.setText(country);
            tvState.setText(state);
            tvCity.setText(city);
            tvPincode.setText(postalCode);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_myloc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:text="fetch address"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Full Address : "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Feature : "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFeature"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Country : "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCountry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="State : "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvState"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="City : "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pincode : "
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPincode"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Extends with `Fragment` instead of `Activity` and use related method and context of it.

Comment: i got some error

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to fragment.. and i hope you know how to call fragment.

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Location mLocation;
    //  private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener listener;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2 * 1000;  /* 10 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 2000; /* 2 sec */
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private Double latitude = 0.00;
    private Double longitude = 0.00;
    private TextView textView, tvCountry, tvCity, tvState, tvPincode, tvFeature;
    private Button btn;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myloc,container,false);
    init(view);
    return view;
}

private void init(View view) {
    requestMultiplePermissions();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    //  mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    checkLocation();

    textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tvCountry = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
    tvState = view.findViewById(R.id.tvState);
    tvCity = view.findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
    tvPincode = view.findViewById(R.id.tvPincode);
    tvFeature = view.findViewById(R.id.tvFeature);
    btn = fview.indViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAddress(latitude,longitude);
        }
    });
}


@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        startLocationUpdates();

        mLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if(mLocation == null){
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
        if (mLocation != null) {

            // mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
            //mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location not Detected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed. Error: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Create the location request
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL)
                .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        // Request location updates
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d("reque", "--->>>>");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    private boolean checkLocation() {
        if(!isLocationEnabled())
            showAlert();
        return isLocationEnabled();
    }

    private void showAlert() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Enable Location")
                .setMessage("Your Locations Settings is set to 'Off'.\nPlease Enable Location to " +
                        "use this app")
                .setPositiveButton("Location Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {

                    }
                });
        dialog.show();
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
                locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }

    private void  requestMultiplePermissions(){
        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All permissions are granted by user!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //startLocationUpdates();
                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // show alert dialog navigating to Settings
                            openSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Some Error! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
    }

    private void openSettingsDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Required Permissions");
        builder.setMessage("This app require permission to use awesome feature. Grant them in app settings.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Take Me To SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                intent.setData(uri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    private void setAddress(Double latitude, Double longitude){

        Geocoder geocoder;
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        try {
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(addresses.size() > 0) {
            Log.d("max", " " + addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex());

            String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
            String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
            String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
            String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

            addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
            textView.setText(address);
            tvFeature.setText(knownName);
            tvCountry.setText(country);
            tvState.setText(state);
            tvCity.setText(city);
            tvPincode.setText(postalCode);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Activity , you are extending with AppCompact activity.Same way , you need to extend fragment with Fragment .

For context , wherever you are using "this" , replace it by "getActivity()" or "getContext()".

Fragment has a method called onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle). Override it, inflate using the layout and return the view.

Inflate you view in onCreateView eg :

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
}
```

Call rest of your method in Override method onViewCreate() method of fragment . Or else you call those method in onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)  method .

Call these methods in onViewCreate:

```
    requestMultiplePermissions();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

  //  mLocationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    checkLocation();

    textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tvCountry = findViewById(R.id.tvCountry);
    tvState = findViewById(R.id.tvState);
    tvCity = findViewById(R.id.tvCity);
    tvPincode = findViewById(R.id.tvPincode);
    tvFeature = findViewById(R.id.tvFeature);
    btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setAddress(latitude,longitude);
        }
    });
```

For more info , you may use the below link for detailed info on fragment.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating

Comment: thank you ^^ in the end cancel the Fragment job, I do it by Activity